# How to make Vundle work with out connection to the internet?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, vundle

**How to make Vundle work with out connection to the internet?**

*I don't have internet connection on my work machine (Windows). But I can place the required files in following folder (.vim\bundle).*

When I try to install plugins **"BundleInstall"**  the following errors appears. I can understand it is trying to fetch from **github**.

*So, how can I override this behavior*

```
[130716 12:56:44]                                                  
[130716 12:56:44] Bundle gmarik/vundle                             
[130716 12:56:44] $ git clone --recursive "https://github.com/     
...gmarik/vundle.git" "C:\Users\vramaraj\.vim\bundle\vundle"       
[130716 12:56:44] > Cloning into 'C:\Users\vramaraj\.              
...vim\bundle\vundle'...^@                                         
[130716 12:56:45]                                                  
[130716 12:56:45] Helptags:                                        
[130716 12:56:45] Helptags: 0 bundles processed
```

Comment: Vundle's issue tracker is [that way](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle/issues?page=1&state=closed).

Comment: Are you using `BundleInstall` in your .vimrc or just `Bundle`?  IIRC `Bundle` shouldn't be fetching anything on its own (but it's been a while since I've messed with it).

Comment: I support your question, It seems to me, that I need make vim bundle at home and bring it to work